# Remove multiple empty lines from text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a text file where data is something like this,

```
Hosts 
-------------
 

 host id          | hostname                
------------------+-------------------------------------------
 651              | host1
 652              | host2

Guests 
------------
 

 guest id         | guestname 
------------------+-----------
 61               | guest1
```

I need to remove the 2 empty lines but leave the single empty lines to differentiate. Tried below for loop but that deletes all the records.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("test.txt") do (echo(%%a)>>~.txt
move /y  ~.txt "test.txt"
```

The expected result is like below

```
Hosts 
-------------
 host id          | hostname                
------------------+-------------------------------------------
 651              | host1
 652              | host2

Guests 
------------
 guest id         | guestname 
------------------+-----------
 61               | guest1
```

Comment: I'd suggest you look at `sed`, `awk` or `gawk` -use Google to find a free port

Answer (score 3):

You could utilise the [`findstr` command](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) which supports a tiny subset of regular expressions:

- In Command Prompt:

  ```cmd
  >>> for %L in (^"^
  ... 
  ... ^") do @for /F %C in ('copy /Z "%ComSpec%" nul') do @findstr /V /R /C:"^ *%~C%~L *%~C%~L.*|.*$" /C:"^ *%~C%~L.*|.*$" "test.txt"
  ```
- In a batch script:

  ```cmd
  @echo off
  for %%L in (^"^
  %= blank line =%
  ^") do (
      for /F %%C in ('copy /Z "%ComSpec%" nul') do (
          findstr /V /R /C:"^ *%%~C%%~L *%%~C%%~L.*|.*$" /C:"^ *%%~C%%~L.*|.*$" "test.txt"
      )
  )
  ```

This code assumes that the text file contains DOS/Windows-style line-breaks consisting of a carriage-return (CR, ASCII `0x0D`) and a line-feed (LF, ASCII `0x0A`) character.